# Reference: Wittgenstein teaching mathematics

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Can anyone give me any reference concerning L.Wittgenstein teaching school kids mathematics? I have been wondering what kind of mathematics he taught and how he lectured the material.

Comment: Look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein#Teaching_posts_in_Austria, and references 98 to 102

Comment: It seems you could get your answers in http://www.amazon.com/Ludwig-Wittgenstein-The-Duty-Genius/dp/0140159959